# Complex SQL request

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a table in my sql database with this structure

[image]

```
USE [XXXXX]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [PoSId] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [EditorCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [ProductCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EditionCode] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [IssueDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FeedbackType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FeedbackRef] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreationTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModificationTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

FeedbackType" attribute accept 4 potential values : "DELIVERY", "RESTOCKING", "MISSING", "UNSOLD

I created an sql script which gives me the sum of missing quantity for a dedicated pointOfSale, productCode, editionCode, and issue date.

```
  SELECT [PoSId]
      ,[ProductCode]
      ,[EditionCode]
      ,[IssueDate]
      , CASE WHEN Quantity < 0 THEN Quantity * -1 ELSE Quantity END AS QuantityMissing
FROM (
SELECT [PoSId]
      ,[ProductCode]
      ,[EditionCode]
      ,[IssueDate]
      ,SUM([Quantity]) AS Quantity
  FROM [xxxxxxx].[dbo].[Sales]
  Where FeedbackType='MISSING' and IssueDate < '2019-12-18'
  AND CreationTime < '2019-12-19'
  GROUP BY [PoSId]
      ,[ProductCode]
      ,[EditionCode]
      ,[IssueDate]
  ) T

  ORDER by IssueDate
```

Until now, the script do what I need (adding a column for missing quantities)

Now, I need to modify this script to do this :

1- add a new column for the sum of "Unsold" quantities named "Unsold_qty"

2- add another column for the sum of "Sold" quantities named "Sold_qty" which is calculated based on this formula => SOLD qty = DELIVERY qty - MISSING qty - UNSOLD qty

How can I modify my script to create these two new columns ?

The result I need is something like this :

[image]

PS : don't forget that my "where" condition in this script take into account only missing quantities (Where FeedbackType='MISSING') => to do what I need now I suppose we need change this "where" condition or maybe do another where condition anywhere else.

Thank you in advance for any help !

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called conditional aggregation.

One way to do it is to put the `CASE` expression inside the `SUM`.

```
SELECT 
    [PoSId]
    ,[ProductCode]
    ,[EditionCode]
    ,[IssueDate]
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN FeedbackType='MISSING'  THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) AS QuantityMissing
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN FeedbackType='UNSOLD'   THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) AS QuantityUnsold
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN FeedbackType='DELIVERY' THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) AS QuantityDelivery

    ,SUM(CASE WHEN FeedbackType='DELIVERY' THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) 
    -SUM(CASE WHEN FeedbackType='MISSING'  THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) 
    -SUM(CASE WHEN FeedbackType='UNSOLD'   THEN [Quantity] ELSE 0 END) AS QuantitySold

FROM
    [xxxxxxx].[dbo].[Sales]
WHERE
    IssueDate < '2019-12-18'
    AND CreationTime < '2019-12-19'
GROUP BY 
    [PoSId]
    ,[ProductCode]
    ,[EditionCode]
    ,[IssueDate]
ORDER BY 
    IssueDate
;
```

Adjust +- as needed (whether you add or subtract some of the sums, it is not clear from the question).